# server tags in markup

Tags: c#, asp.net

Morning all I have frequently used the old

```
<asp:Label ID="lblWas" runat="server" Text='<%# XPath("FACEVALUE") %>'></asp:Label>
```

This type of thing. when I first came across it I loved it, i'm using it again today but not quite so simply.

I have a number of extra things I would like to achieve.

1. Apply formatting to the value. Like `Text='<%# string.Format(XPath("FACEVALUE"), "{0:c}") %>'>`
2. `<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBook" runat="server" PostBackUrl='/THEATRE/' + XPath("FACEVALUE")>Book</asp:LinkButton>`

For option number 2 the URL is not as I would expect, and for number 1 I cannot get the syntax correct if it's even possible.

I have not been able to find something suitable in google. Hopefully what I am trying to achieve is obvious from the example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [TemplateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.aspx).[XPath(string xPathExpression, string format)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttb5t300.aspx) override:

```
<asp:Label Text='<%# XPath("FACEVALUE", "{0:c}") %>' />
<asp:LinkButton Text="..." PostBackUrl='<%# XPath("FACEVALUE", "/THEATRE/{0}") %>' />
```

As you can see, you do not need to use string.Format because you can pass the format directly into the XPath method!

Comment: Well since XPath actually takes a format expression this has to be the neater option, however it's simply ignoring my format expression.  The value passed is 55 and when using "{0:C}" it outputs 60. So not quite ignoring me but I expected £55 :)

Comment: It's because the string is a string,  you need to pass an int to the formatter for it to show as a monetary value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe for #1, you have messed up the syntax, you want to use

```
Text='<%# string.Format("{0:c}", XPath("FACEVALUE")) %>'
```

or `Text='<%# XPath("FACEVALUE", "{0:c}") %>'`

For #2, you need to use data binding expressions

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBook" runat="server" PostBackUrl='<%# "/THEATRE/" + XPath("FACEVALUE")%>'>Book</asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first thing it must be `Text='<%# string.Format( "{0:c}",XPath("FACEVALUE")) %>'>`

and for the second one it should be

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBook" runat="server" PostBackUrl='/THEATRE/ + <%# XPath("FACEVALUE") %>'>Book</asp:LinkButton>
```